# vue.config.js optimization.splitChunks breaks unit tests in fresh project

Tags: vue.js, webpack-4

Adding splitchunks webpack optimization with maxSize < 1077900 in a freshly initialized vue project breaks unit tests.

- vue cli: 3.9.0
- webpack: 4.41.5

Anyone have any idea what would cause this?

Files produced in build:

```
File                                      Size             Gzipped

  dist/js/chunk-vendors~d939e436.1b1a6c4    89.15 KiB        31.95 KiB
  d.js
  dist/js/app~d0ae3f07.be737b26.js          4.81 KiB         1.68 KiB
  dist/css/app~d0ae3f07.0dca8a5d.css        0.33 KiB         0.23 KiB
```

yarn run test:unit

```
WEBPACK  Compiling...

  [=========================] 98% (after emitting)

 DONE  Compiled successfully in 2010ms

  [=========================] 100% (completed)

 WEBPACK  Compiled successfully in 2010ms

 MOCHA  Testing...

 RUNTIME EXCEPTION  Exception occurred while loading your tests

TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
    at __webpack_require__ (/Project/Path/testvuetest/dist/js/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap:19:1)
    at /Project/Path/testvuetest/dist/js/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap:83:1
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Project/Path/testvuetest/dist/js/main~._node_modules_@.js:87:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30)
    at Object._module2.default._extensions.<computed> [as .js] (/Project/Path/testvuetest/node_modules/mochapack/src/util/registerRequireHook.js:99:12)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:852:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at /Project/Path/testvuetest/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:334:36
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Mocha.loadFiles (/Project/Path/testvuetest/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:331:14)
    at Mocha.run (/Project/Path/testvuetest/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:809:10)
    at cb (/Project/Path/testvuetest/node_modules/mochapack/src/runner/TestRunner.js:96:21)
    at /Project/Path/testvuetest/node_modules/mochapack/src/webpack/compiler/registerReadyCallback.js:12:7
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/Project/Path/testvuetest/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:45:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/Project/Path/testvuetest/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
    at /Project/Path/testvuetest/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:304:22
    at Compiler.emitRecords (/Project/Path/testvuetest/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:499:39)
    at /Project/Path/testvuetest/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:298:10
    at /Project/Path/testvuetest/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:485:14
    at eval (eval at create (/Project/Path/testvuetest/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:16:1)
    at /Project/Path/testvuetest/node_modules/copy-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:115:7
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/Project/Path/testvuetest/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:12:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/Project/Path/testvuetest/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
    at /Project/Path/testvuetest/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:482:27
    at /Project/Path/testvuetest/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:2818:7
    at done (/Project/Path/testvuetest/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:3522:9)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/Project/Path/testvuetest/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at /Project/Path/testvuetest/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:464:33
    at MemoryFileSystem.writeFile (/Project/Path/testvuetest/node_modules/memory-fs/lib/MemoryFileSystem.js:328:9)
    at writeOut (/Project/Path/testvuetest/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:462:30)
    at Immediate._onImmediate (/Project/Path/testvuetest/node_modules/memory-fs/lib/MemoryFileSystem.js:288:4)
    at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:439:21)

 ERROR  mochapack exited with code 1.
```

Comment: I faced with same problems too. In my vue.config.js I use optimization optimization: {
       splitChunks: {
         minSize: 10000,
         maxSize: 250000
       }
     } and if I had commented it - tests were worked well again.